# Transpose Excel Row Data into columns based on Unique Identifier

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel table in below format.

Sr. No.    Column 1 (X)    Column 2(Y)    Column 3(Z)

1                      X                      Y                     Z
2                                               Y                    Z
3                                               Y
4                               X                                  Y
5                               X

I want to tranpose it in following format in MS Excel.

Sr. No.     Value
1                          X
1                          Y
1                          Z
2                          Y
2                          Z
3                          Y
4                          X
4                          Y
5                          X

Actual data contains more than 30 columns which needs to be transposed into 2 columns. 
Please guide me.

Comment: Did you work out anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select complete table data and then name it as `SourceData` using

   > Formula>Name Manager
2. Now implement following formula for getting first column:

`=INDEX(SourceData,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/(COLUMNS(SourceData)-1),1),1)`

And for second column:

`=INDEX(SourceData,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/(COLUMNS(SourceData)-1),1),MOD(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1,COLUMNS(SourceData)-1)+2)`

3. Copy and paste special values and then delete blanks / zeroes.

You will get result as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using other databases, there might be a formal unpivot operator/function available.  But in MySQL, this is not a possibility.  However, one approach which should work here would be to just take a union of the three columns:

```
SELECT 1 AS sr_no, col1 AS value WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, col2 WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, col3 WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sr_no;
```